# Weird shadows in cycles render

Tags: rendering

I noticed when I render my low poly tree I get this weird shadows/almost unfinished rendering. The render looks all pixelated. What i'm I doing wrong, i'm a complete beginner. thanks! Also i'm using filmic blender.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You haven't rendered anything yet. That's just cycles render preview which uses less samples. You can increase the samples in the render properties. Pressing 'F12' with a camera object in your scene will use the default 128 samples and look much better. The noise in your image is considered normal for the settings.

Preview:
[image]

vs

Render at 300 samples:
[image]